# Angular 10 - Build errors based on position of element

Tags: angular, typescript, build, angular-cli

In Angular 10, I'm getting the following build error when running 'ng serve' or 'ng build'.

```
ERROR in projects/project-navigator/src/app/modals/building-permissions.component.html:89:61 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

    89         <button type="button" (click)="doneButtonClicked()" [ngClass]="{ 'inactive-button': !permissionsHaveChanged || noOwner || (customMessageContainsHyperlinks && !allTogglesOff) }" twgTooltip [ttTextOnly]="doneDisabledTooltip" [ttDontShowIf]="permissionsHaveChanged && !noOwner && (!customMessageContainsHyperlinks || allTogglesOff)">
                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      projects/project-navigator/src/app/modals/building-permissions.component.ts:18:16
        18   templateUrl: './building-permissions.component.html',
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component BuildingPermissionsComponent.
    projects/project-navigator/src/app/modals/building-permissions.component.html:89:197 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ttTextOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

    89         <button type="button" (click)="doneButtonClicked()" [ngClass]="{ 'inactive-button': !permissionsHaveChanged || noOwner || (customMessageContainsHyperlinks && !allTogglesOff) }" twgTooltip [ttTextOnly]="doneDisabledTooltip" [ttDontShowIf]="permissionsHaveChanged && !noOwner && (!customMessageContainsHyperlinks || allTogglesOff)">
                                                                                                                                                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      projects/project-navigator/src/app/modals/building-permissions.component.ts:18:16
        18   templateUrl: './building-permissions.component.html',
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component BuildingPermissionsComponent.
    projects/project-navigator/src/app/modals/building-permissions.component.html:89:232 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ttDontShowIf' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

    89         <button type="button" (click)="doneButtonClicked()" [ngClass]="{ 'inactive-button': !permissionsHaveChanged || noOwner || (customMessageContainsHyperlinks && !allTogglesOff) }" twgTooltip [ttTextOnly]="doneDisabledTooltip" [ttDontShowIf]="permissionsHaveChanged && !noOwner && (!customMessageContainsHyperlinks || allTogglesOff)">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      projects/project-navigator/src/app/modals/building-permissions.component.ts:18:16
        18   templateUrl: './building-permissions.component.html',
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component BuildingPermissionsComponent.
```

The errors reference this button:

```
<button type="button" (click)="doneButtonClicked()" [ngClass]="{ 'inactive-button': !permissionsHaveChanged || noOwner || (customMessageContainsHyperlinks && !allTogglesOff) }" twgTooltip [ttTextOnly]="doneDisabledTooltip" [ttDontShowIf]="permissionsHaveChanged && !noOwner && (!customMessageContainsHyperlinks || allTogglesOff)">
          {{continueToNotifications && !showNotificationForm ? "Continue" : "Apply Changes" }}
        </button>
```

But, these errors are incorrect, given the following facts:

- I've verified all the variables referenced for the button do exist in the component ts file. Plus, if it were the variables, the errors would say so.
- I've looked for html issues like a missing end tag or a quote not terminated...found nothing
- Other elements, including buttons, in the same component template are using the ngClass, ttTextOnly, and ttDontShowIf the same exact way with no error.
- If cut and paste the button to a different part of the template, it builds fine, validating that there are in fact no syntax errors here.
- If I remove the button and add a span in place of it like this, it errors out too: <span [ngClass]="{'woot': true}">my span
- If I add an *ngIf="true" to the element that's a parent to the button, I get no build error.

So, it seems to make no sense. I can move the button to various parts of the template and it errors out in some places near the bottom of the template, but doesn't error out in most places of the template. So the position of the button seems to be causing the errors. I don't get it.

Does anyone have ideas for what could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The issue seems to have been that I didn't declare my component in my app.module.ts file. Because of this, I suspect it the dependencies like the FormsModule and others, weren't being recognized during compilation. This is a result of me not adding components via the CLI, but instead right-clicking and creating typescript files in Visual Studio.